# Problemas con Tkinter en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, selenium

Tengo este codigo:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sys

def oneclick():
  if True:
  pass
  else:
  sys.exit(). sys.exit()



def show_entry_fields():
    print("Email: %s\nPassword: %s\nRepeat: %s\nTime: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get(), e3.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master,
         text="Email").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master,
         text="Password").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(master,
        text="Repeat").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(master,
        text="Time").grid(row=3)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)
e4 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

Button = tk.Button()
tk.Button(master,
          text='Start',
          command=oneclick).grid(row=4,
                                    column=1,
                                    sticky=tk.W,
                                    pady=4)

master.title("Presearch by meganano202")
master.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\meganano202\\Desktop\\bot\\G_XURdf8.ico")

# Configuración de la raíz
def menubar():

  root = Tk()

  menubar = Menu(root)
  root.config(menu=menubar)

  filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
  filemenu.add_command(label="Nuevo")
  filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir")
  filemenu.add_command(label="Guardar")
  filemenu.add_command(label="Cerrar")
  filemenu.add_separator()
  filemenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=root.quit)

  editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
  editmenu.add_command(label="Cortar")
  editmenu.add_command(label="Copiar")
  editmenu.add_command(label="Pegar")

  helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
  helpmenu.add_command(label="Ayuda")
  helpmenu.add_separator()
  helpmenu.add_command(label="Acerca de...")

  menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=filemenu)
  menubar.add_cascade(label="Editar", menu=editmenu)
  menubar.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=helpmenu)

tk.mainloop()


from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\meganano202\\Desktop\\bot\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://presearch.org/login")
time.sleep(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name ("email")
elem.send_keys(e1.get())
time.sleep(4)
password_elem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password_elem.send_keys(e2.get())
time.sleep(60)
for i in range(e3.get()):
    search_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("search").send_keys("meganano202")
    search_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
    time.sleep(e4.get())
    driver.back()
```

Y lo que querría hacer es, cuando no presionen el botón de "Start" que no se inicie el bot, es decir, cuando presione Start que se inicie y se cierre la venta automáticamente ( que creo que ya lo hice yo ) y cuando se cierre la ventana manualmente que no se inicie el bot, como veis yo intente hacerlo con `if` y `else` pero no me funciono o lo hice mal. Estaré muy agradecido por su ayuda

Comment: Por favor no pongas un enlace con tu código, pon tu código aqui. Un saludo

Comment: claro, un momento

Comment: Muchas gracias! mas que nada porque el link puede dejar de ser accesible y tu pregunta no tendria sentido ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una variable global al inicio de tu *script*, por ejemplo:

```
iniciar_bot = False
```

Redefine tu función *oneclick* así:

```
def oneclick():
    global iniciar_bot
    iniciar_bot = True
    master.destroy()
```

De este modo, al pulsar el botón *Start* la función **Tk.destroy** cierra el formulario. Ahora tienes que incluir el código del "bot" en un condicional para que solo se ejecute si se pulsó *Start* (donde se asignó *iniciar_bot = True*), y no se ejecute si se cerró el formulario presionando **X**.

```
if iniciar_bot == True:
    # El código del bot
```

Si no quieres meter todo ese código dentro de una condición, antes de este puedes hacer esta comprobación (el resultado será el mismo):

```
import os

if not iniciar_bot:
    os._exit(0)
```

**EDITO:**

Al utilizar `master.destroy()` ya no puedes acceder a los valores de los *Entry* (e1, e2, e3 y e4), ya que "destruiste" el formulario con todos sus *widgets*.

La solución que he aplicado es obtener los valores de los *Entry* dentro de la función `oneclick` y asignarlos a las *variables globales* e1, e2, e3 y e4. Aquí tienes el código:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

iniciar_bot = False
e1 = ""
e2 = ""
e3 = ""
e4 = ""


def oneclick():
    global iniciar_bot, e1, e2, e3, e4
    iniciar_bot = True
    e1, e2, e3, e4 = e1.get(), e2.get(), e3.get(), e4.get()
    master.destroy()



def show_entry_fields():
    print("Email: %s\nPassword: %s\nRepeat: %s\nTime: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get(), e3.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master,
         text="Email").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master,
         text="Password").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(master,
        text="Repeat").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(master,
        text="Time").grid(row=3)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)
e4 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

Button = tk.Button()
tk.Button(master,
          text='Start',
          command=oneclick).grid(row=4,
                                    column=1,
                                    sticky=tk.W,
                                    pady=4)

master.title("Presearch by meganano202")
master.iconbitmap("C:\\Users\\meganano202\\Desktop\\bot\\G_XURdf8.ico")

# Configuración de la raíz
def menubar():

  root = Tk()

  menubar = Menu(root)
  root.config(menu=menubar)

  filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
  filemenu.add_command(label="Nuevo")
  filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir")
  filemenu.add_command(label="Guardar")
  filemenu.add_command(label="Cerrar")
  filemenu.add_separator()
  filemenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=root.quit)

  editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
  editmenu.add_command(label="Cortar")
  editmenu.add_command(label="Copiar")
  editmenu.add_command(label="Pegar")

  helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
  helpmenu.add_command(label="Ayuda")
  helpmenu.add_separator()
  helpmenu.add_command(label="Acerca de...")

  menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=filemenu)
  menubar.add_cascade(label="Editar", menu=editmenu)
  menubar.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=helpmenu)

master.mainloop()




if iniciar_bot == True:
  from selenium import webdriver
  import time

  driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
  driver.get("https://presearch.org/login")
  time.sleep(2)
  elem = driver.find_element_by_name ("email")
  elem.send_keys(e1)
  time.sleep(4)
  password_elem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
  password_elem.send_keys(e2)
  time.sleep(60)
  for i in range(int(e3)):
      search_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("search").send_keys("meganano202")
      search_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
      time.sleep(int(e4))
      driver.back()
```

De esta manera, en el *bot* sustituye *e1.get()* por `e1` (que no se refiere al *Entry e1*, sino a la *variable global e1* que ahora contiene el valor del *Entry* (lo mismo para `e2`, `e3` y `e4`).

También he sustituido `tk.mainloop()` por `master.mainloop()`. No se si esto tiene algún impacto, pero en toda la documentación que he visto sobre *tkinter* siempre se hace así y por tanto yo siempre lo hago así jeje.

Un saludo.

Comment: Bua!!! muchísimas gracias!! Ahora tengo otro problema, aparece todo correcto cuando lo ejecuto, pero cuando sale el webdriver y carga la pagina aparece este error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/meganano202/Desktop/MEGA/bot/presearch.pyw", line 83, in <module>
    elem.send_keys(e1.get())
  File "C:\Users\meganano202\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2682, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"` . Sabes a que se debe? el código es el mismo pero con tus aportaciones. Saludos

Comment: Me alegro de que te funcione! Cuando tenga tiempo le echo un vistazo al error del que hablas por si aún no lo solucionaste. Suerte!

Comment: Hola amigo, he revisado el error que comentaste. El problema es que después de usar `master.destroy()` dentro de la función `oneclick()` ya no existen los *Entrys* e1, e2, e3 y e4, y ya no puedes obtener su valor con el método *.get()*. Voy a actualizar mi respuesta con el código completamente corregido, a ver si te sirve. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, te agregare a los créditos del bot. Aun que me sigue apareciendo este error: `File "C:/Users/meganano202/Desktop/MEGA/bot/presearch.pyw", line 101, in <module>
    for i in range(e3):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Eso es porque `e3` es una cadena de texto, si quieres usar ese valor como un número conviértelo a *int*: for i in range(int(e3)). Haz lo mismo para `e4`: time.sleep(int(e4)). No estuve atento a esto jeje, ya lo he corregido en la respuesta.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias por todo. Estoy muy agradecido, ojala q hubiera mas gente en el mundo/esta pagina, como tu.

Abrazos

Comment: De nada!! ha sido un placer ayudar. Cuando vi tu pregunta recordé que precisamente yo una vez estuve intentando hacer algo parecido (con *selenium* y *tkinter*). Pasé bastante tiempo hasta que encontré como hacerlo (porque de *tkinter* no hay demasiada documentación en español). En fin, un abrazo y que se de bien!! :)